# What is a notation '1' in risk neutral probabilities paper?

Tags: portfolio-management, risk-management, self-study, notation

I'm reading the paper by [Zhao et al (2008)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377221706006278) and have a problem with used definitions in the text on the page 1535.

> First, we generate a sample, $R$, of a given size from the distribution (21). Let $\hat{\mu}$ and $\hat{\sigma}^2$ be the sample mean vector and the sample variance covariance matrix. Then, we modify the generated sample
>   to $$\hat{R}=\mu + (R-\hat{\mu})\hat{\sigma}^{-1}\sigma.$$
>   Then, the modified sample $\hat{R}$ has the same first and second moments as the original distribution.
>   To further test, whether the modified sample is arbitrage free, we use
>   the Matlab backslash function to examine whether the solution to 
>   $(1 + R)^{\top} \backslash 1$ is componentwise positive.

**Question.** What means $1$ in the last line? Is it an identity matrix or a column vector of ones? And what is dimensions of this $1$?

I have tried to examine the solution from Table 1.

```
library(pracma)

n <- 5

R<-matrix(
c(
0.0025, 0.0377, 0.0110, 0.0769, 0.0047,
0.0025, 0.0431, 0.0001, 0.0045, 0.0562,
0.0025, 0.0469, 0.0643, 0.0400, 0.0370,
0.0025, 0.0504, 0.0422, 0.0169, 0.0333,
0.0025, 0.0596, 0.0038, 0.1896, 0.0663), ncol=n)

#I<-ones(n)
I <-diag(n)

mldivide(t(I+R),I)
```

**Add after JejeBelfort's comment.** If the $1$ is a column vector of ones then what is $+$? Union operation or Kronecker product operator?

```
I <- rep(1, n)
cbind(I, R)
```

**Reference.**

Yonggan Zhao, William T. Ziemba (2008) Calculating risk neutral probabilities and optimal portfolio policies in a dynamic investment model
with downside risk control. European Journal of Operational Research 185 (2008) 1525–1540.

Comment: In MATLAB backslash is a linear equation solver, possibly using least squares, https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com Also called "mldivide".

Comment: I guess it is the vector composed of ones only, of size equal to the number of rows in $R$.

Comment: Left argument of '\' is a possibly non-square matrix, right argument is a column vector (in this case all ones).

Comment: @JejeBelfort, thanks you for comment. If '1' is the vector what is '+'? Union operation?

Comment: @Nick Do you mean the $\intercal$ operator? This should represent the matrix transpose operator applied to $(1+R)$.

Comment: @JejeBelfort, I mean $+$ operator, i don't know how to make summation a vector $1$ and a matrix $R$.

Comment: @Nick I am pretty sure it is the component wise addition of an element of $1$ and the corresponding element in $R$. However, I agree with you, it is not clear what is this $1$. If it was the identity matrix, I hope the author would have been smart enough to write $I$. So I would say it represents the matrix of ones. Again, I cannot access the original document so it is hard to say...

Comment: @JejeBelfort, in private communication the author wtore that $1$ is the vector ones but he don't wrote the comment about $+$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The 1 you are referring to is a vector of ones

The expression  $(1 + R)^T \backslash 1$ appears to be shorthand for a MATLAB equation such as:

`s = (ones(n,k) + R)' \ ones(n, 1)`

where `R` is an `n` by `k` matrix (i.e. specifying returns for $n$ periods of $k$ assets).

`1 + R` adds 1 to each element of the matrix R (eg. makes it a return like 1.02 instead of .02). The MATLAB command `\` would solve the below system for $\mathbf{s}$ in the least squares sense:

$$ ( 1 + R)^T \mathbf{s} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ \ldots \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} $$

### A non-negative solution $\mathbf{s}$ guarantees the absence of arbitrage

Any solution $\mathbf{s}$ to this linear system will be a vector of state prices for the $n$ states that satisfies the Law of One Price (LOOP). For any asset $i$, the inner product of the return series and the state price vector gives the value 1 which is the price of a return.

$$ (1 + \mathbf{r}_i)^T \mathbf{s} = 1$$

If $\mathbf{s}$ correctly prices each asset, the Law of One Price is satisfied. No arbitrage is a somewhat different condition though.

The existence of a non-negative state price vector $\mathbf{s}$ implies the absence of arbitrage. A positive payoff with a strictly negative cost is called an *arbitrage*. If the state price density (stochastic discount factor) is positive, then one cannot construct an arbitrage.

(Note: I'm using bold letters for vectors.)

#### Farkas's Lemma and No Arbitrage

By [Farkas's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farkas%27_lemma), exactly one of the following conditions holds:

1. There exists a state price vector $\mathbf{s} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $(1+R)^T \mathbf{s} = \mathbf{1}$ and $\mathbf{s} \geq 0$
2. There exists a $\mathbf{w} \in \mathbb{R}^k$ (giving investments in the $k$ assets) such that $(1+R)\mathbf{w} \geq 0$ and $\mathbf{1}^T \mathbf{w} < 0$

Condition (1) is the existence of a non-negative state price vector $\mathbf{s}$.Condition (2) implies it's possible to construct an arbitrage:

- Investing $w_i$ in asset $i$ gives the non-negative payoff $(1 + R) \mathbf{w} \geq 0$
- The portfolio has a negative cost since $ \mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{1} < 0$.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean when you say that 1 is "the price of a return"? I didn't get that part. Thanks.

Comment: @noob2 Let $X$ be some future payoff. Let $p(X)$ be today's price for that future payoff. Any payoff $X$ with a price of 1 is a return. I can pay 1 dollar and get the risk free rate tomorrow. I can pay 1 dollar and get the return on Apple tomorrow etc...    For any arbitrary payoff $X$, you can construct the associated return as $R = \frac{X}{p(X)}$. Then $p\left(R \right)  = p\left( \frac{X}{p(X)} \right) = \frac{p(X)}{p(X)} = 1$ where the 2nd to last step comes from the linearity of the pricing function (an assumption).